# Tensorflow models in production on Google Cloud

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google Cloud Platform. Coming from the Data Science side, I am surprised by how unintuitively it is to use. I am an experienced Tensorflow user on GPUs locally, but running a model on GCP seems like an impossible task.

Where does the code reside, or where is the model stored, when a Tensorflow model is deployed to production on GCP?

Most of the demos out there are just focusing on getting a first result to screen, without really showing how things are put to work.

Comment: This is an “I want a pony” question and it’s too broad to give a specific technical answer, making it off-topic here on Stack Overflow. You’ll need to attempt to solve this problem and show your code so we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level as well as to demonstrate your commitment to solving this problem.

Comment: Your comment is not very helpful. My question is about best practice for putting an algorithm into production on a commonly used platform. My code is a script that trains a model. It would not add anything to the question. @tadman

Comment: "Best practice" questions fall under the recommendations banner and those are off-topic. See [Point 4](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This is because best practices are just opinions, not specific technical answers, and may not apply in your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my procedure for running TensorFlow on Google's Machine Learning Engine:

1. Upload training data to a Cloud Storage bucket.
2. Create a formal package for the TensorFlow application, including setup.py.
3. Execute `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training` with flags that identify the local package, the bucket with the training data, and the bucket that should hold the training results.
4. Execute `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit prediction` with flags that identify the bucket containing training results and the bucket that should contain the prediction results.

I prefer to execute the `gcloud ml-engine` commands locally first, so that I can take care of any errors. I've never used Datalab with the ML Engine.